# Google maps api. The algorithm gives not correct results

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Task: show the points from excel prepared, which lie along the route (for example, Moscow-Bryansk). The algorithm is below. The problem is that the points that lie on the path (with their usual output) are not found by the algorithm. Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

```
 directionsService.route(request, function (result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
        calcNearDots(result);
    } else {
        if (status == "ZERO_RESULTS") {
            alert("Ошибка. Невозможно проложить маршрут.");
        } else {
            alert("Ошибка");
        }
        toggleVoile();
    }
});

function calcNearDots(route) {
var steps = route.routes[0].legs[0].steps;
for (i in steps) {
    var arr = {
        'lat': steps[i].start_location.lat(),
        'lng': steps[i].start_location.lng()
    };

    closests = closests.concat(findClosestMarker(arr, radius));

}
}
function rad(x) {
    return x * Math.PI / 180;
}

function findClosestMarker(dot, radius) {
   var lat = dot.lat;
   var lng = dot.lng;
   var R = 6371;
   var dots = [];
   //gmarkers массив который содержит точки из экселя 
   for (var i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
        var mlat = gmarkers[i].position.lat();
        var mlng = gmarkers[i].position.lng();
        var dLat = rad(mlat - lat);
        var dLong = rad(mlng - lng);
        var a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) + Math.cos(rad(lat)) * Math.cos(rad(lat)) * Math.sin(dLong / 2) * Math.sin(dLong / 2);

        var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
        var d = R * c;

        if (d < radius) {
            dots.push(gmarkers[i].id);
        }
    }

    return dots;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took a detail inside step

var path = steps[i].path;

findClosestMarker() must be applied for points from each 'path' that are obtained from each 'step'